# custom logging in serilog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, serilog

I am logging using `serilog`. While logging, if I pull the log level to information, I get a lot of logs and my db is bloated. I only want the logs that I have written as the information that I have defined in my controllers to work, but that the high-level logs (warning,error) are automatically thrown. How can I do that?

```
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All;
                logging.RequestHeaders.Add("sec-ch-ua");
                logging.ResponseHeaders.Add("MyResponseHeader");
                logging.MediaTypeOptions.AddText("application/javascript");
                logging.RequestBodyLogLimit = 4096;
                logging.ResponseBodyLogLimit = 4096;
            });
            SqlColumn sqlColumn = new SqlColumn();
            sqlColumn.ColumnName = "UserName";
            sqlColumn.DataType = System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            sqlColumn.PropertyName = "UserName";
            sqlColumn.DataLength = 50;
            sqlColumn.AllowNull = true;
            ColumnOptions columnOpt = new ColumnOptions();
            columnOpt.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
            columnOpt.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
            columnOpt.AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn> { sqlColumn };
     Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt")
                    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                    connectionString: builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlCon"),
                     sinkOptions: new MSSqlServerSinkOptions
                     {
                         AutoCreateSqlTable = true,
                         TableName = "logs",                             
                     },
                     appConfiguration: null,
                     columnOptions: columnOpt        
                    )                        
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.With<CustomUserNameColumn>()
                    .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(a => a.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
                    .CreateLogger();
        builder.Host.UseSerilog(log);
```

Action Method

```
        private readonly ILogger<ConnectionController> logger;
        
        public ConnectionController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, SignInManager<AppUser> signInManager, IMapper mapper, AppDbContext Context, ILogger<ConnectionController> logger) : base(userManager, signInManager, mapper, Context)
                {
                    this.Context = Context;
                    this.logger = logger;
                }
    
      [HttpPost]
      public IActionResult AddConnection(UserViewModel model)
      {
      AppUser searchedUser = userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName).Result;
   var userIsAdded = Context.Users
                        .Where(x => x.UserConnection.Contains(CurrentUser) || x.MainUser.Contains(CurrentUser))
                        .ToList();
      foreach (var item in userIsAdded)
          {
         if (item == searchedUser || searchedUser == CurrentUser)
               {
                            return Redirect($"FindConnection/{model.Search}");
               }
           }
        CurrentUser.UserConnection.Add(searchedUser);
      logger.LogInformation("{0}, {1} ile bağlantı kurdu.", CurrentUser.UserName, searchedUser.UserName);
   Context.SaveChanges();
      if (model.Page == null)
          {
      return Redirect($"/User/ViewProfile/{model.UserName}");
               }
          TempData["page"] = model.Page;
        return Redirect($"FindConnection/{model.Search}");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will only include the log matching with filter.

```
 .UseSerilog((context, loggerConfig) =>
 {
   loggerConfig.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(logevent => logevent.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information);
 })
```

**Update**

for your case , you can directly do the filter while creating the logger object.

```
.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(a =>a.Level == Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)//.MinimumLevel.Warning()
.CreateLogger();
```

Comment: I tried pulling the minimumLevel to information and typing the same code, but this time I couldn't get any logs related to information. The information logs I wrote are normally written, but when I tried your code, I could not see the logs I wrote.

Comment: where exactly you have added the code. in you case you can directly add filter while creating the logger object. i have also put updated version for your case.

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry for the late reply, when I use a filter in `UseSerilog`, I can't get any response to the information name. If I put the filter instead of `MinimumLevel.Warning`, this time it saves all the information along with what comes from the system. I even tried using both together, this time with no results. I think that if there was a problem with my custom log, it would not have written this time, but I will update the question and update it with all the details.

Comment: if this solves your issue , please mark it as accepted ans.

Comment: Of course, I can't confirm it because I can't solve it myself right now, I don't want to mislead anyone.

Comment: you don't need to use both only 2nd approach should be enough. I wonder why it does not work for you. because same code(minimized version) is working for me. can you try only with one sink may be for console first and see if it works.